# Would I be breaking the Google TOS if I hide the Google logo in Android Map SDK while showing only OpenStreetMap tiles?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, openmaptiles

In my app, I'm using [GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) class from the [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) to show maps. However, I'm **not showing** Google's Normal, Hybrid, Satellite or Terrain maps. I'm using that class to show OpenStreeMap tiles using addTileOverlay.

So, since I'm not showing "Google" Maps, would it be illegal or breaking Google TOS if I hide the Google logo?

Comment: It's very likely you would. Please refer to Google's ToS, specifically 3.2.3 (b) https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/

Comment: [Note: As per the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding)

Comment: In addition to @evan's comment take a look at 3.2.4(e): *(e) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google maps in the same Customer Application.*

Comment: @evan Thanks for the links.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Thats very concerning. So I cant even display OSM maps using GoogleMap class?

Comment: @abhiank Seems yes, even with Google logo. But why you need Google Maps core, if you use OSM? It powerful enough itself.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko By Google Maps core do you mean the GoogleMap class or google maps apis likes directions, place search etc?
Right now the app shows both google maps and OSM maps and I'm simply using GoogleMap class to show both as its easier to handle.

Comment: @abhiank Seems it's TOS 3.2.4(e) violation. But I'm not official person of Google.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Hmm seems so. Well, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms), section 3.2.2(b), you will in fact be breaking terms of service:

> "(b) Attribution.  **Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices)**; or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution."